# Printing strings in Assembly, calling that function in C

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, x86-64

all. I was trying to get into programming with NASM, and I also wanted to learn how to make those functions callable in C. I am fairly certain the code that I have so far is correct, in that I need to set up a stack frame, and then undo that stack frame before I return from the routine. I also know I need to return a zero to ensure that there were no errors. I am using debian linux as well, in case I need to adjust for my OS.

The code:

```
global hello

section .data
message:    db "Hello, world!",0 ; A C string needs the null terminator.

section .text
hello:
        push    rbp         ; C calling convention demands that a
        mov     rbp,rsp     ; stack frame be set up like so.

        ;THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC (DOESN'T) HAPPEN

        pop     rbp         ; Restore the stack
        mov     rax,0       ; normal, no error, return value
        ret                 ; return
```

I feel as if I should point out that I ask this because all of the programs I found made external calls to printf. I do not wish to do this, I would really like to learn how to print things in assembly. So I suppose my questions are: What are the calling conventions for C functions in NASM? How do I print a string in NASM 64bit assembly?

Also, to make sure I have this part right, is this the proper way to call the assembly function in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Okay, I was able to work this out. Here's the assembly code. I assembled the `.asm` file along with the `.c` file using `nasm -f elf64 -l hello.lst hello.asm && gcc -o hello hello.c hello.o`

```
section .text
global  hello

hello:
        push    rbp         ; C calling convention demands that a
        mov     rbp,rsp     ; stack frame be set up like so.
        mov     rdx,len     ; Message length
        mov     rcx,message ; Message to be written
        mov     rax,4       ; System call number (sys_write)
        int     0x80        ; Call kernel

        pop     rbp         ; Restore the stack
        mov     rax,0       ; normal, no error, return value
        ret             

section .data
message:    db "Hello, world!",0xa ; 0xa represents the newline char.
len:        equ $ - message
```

The relevant C code (`hello.c`) looked like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Some explanations include the lack of an `#include`, due to the I/O being done in the assembly file. Another thing that I needed to see to believe was that all the work was not done in assembly, as I did not have a `_start` identifier, or whatever that's called. Definitely need to learn more about system calls. Thank you so much to everyone who pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: There is lots of information online discussing [x86-64 calling conventions](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html), particularly from C. Your example code is not 64-bit, although you indicate you wish to use 64-bit. How you print a string in assembler is done by making a system call to the operating system you are using. So it depends upon the operating system.

Comment: The 64bit registers begin with r, right? such as `rax`, `rdi`, etc? I'll edit the post to fix that.

Comment: Yes, they do. But when you get into 64-bit assembler, there's more to it than just putting an `r` in front of the register name. Calling conventions are different than x86.

Comment: A better approach might be to first code your thing in C, then ask the compiler to output the assembler (e.g. `gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -S -O code.c`, then look into `code.s`), to get some initial inspiration

Comment: @lurker, you're right, I should probably have assumed that it wouldn't be that easy. I am using debian linux, if that clarifies anything.

Comment: You'll want to make a call to the `write` system call, then.

Comment: You can find various instantiations of the [Linux 64-bit system calls](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) table online.

Comment: Yes, now I have a better understanding of the system calls, that was definitely my problem. I was actually able to figure it out, I'll edit my post with the solution, though I don't remember how to mark it as answered.

Comment: Note that in x86_64, `syscall` is preferred to `int 0x80` for making system calls.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind. Thank you

Comment: Apologies for the double post, but @PaulGriffiths, when I replaced `int 0x80` with `syscall`, the program no longer outputted "Hello, world!", and printed nothing. I have a feeling this means the call was not being made. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Azhraam: Yes, you can't just replace it, the calling convention is different too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was cleared up in comments, any interaction between the world outside and your code is done through system calls.  C stdio functions format text into an output buffer, then write it with `write(2)`.  Or `read(2)` into an input buffer, and scanf or read lines from that.

Writing in asm doesn't mean you should avoid `libc` functions when they're useful, e.g. printf/scanf.  Usually it only makes sense to write small parts of a program in asm for speed.  e.g. write one function that has a hot loop in asm, and call it from C or whatever other language.  Doing the I/O with all the necessary error-checking of system call return values would not be very fun in asm.  If you're curious what happens under the hood, read the compiler output and/or single-step the asm.  You'll sometimes learn nice tricks from the compiler, and sometimes you'll see it generate less efficient code than you could have written by hand.

---

**This is a problem**:

```
mov     rax,4       ; System call number (sys_write)
int     0x80        ; Call kernel
```

Although 64bit processes can use the i386 `int 0x80` system call ABI, it *is* the 32bit ABI, with only 32bit pointers and so on.  You will have a problem as soon as you go to `write(2)` a char array that's on the stack (since amd64 Linux processes start with a stack pointer that has the high bits set.  Heap memory, and `.data` and `.rodata` memory mapped from the executable are mapped into the lower 32b of address space.)

The native amd64 ABI uses `syscall`, and the system call numbers aren't the same as the i386 ABI.  I found [this table of syscalls](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/) listing the number and which parameter goes in which register.  `sys/syscall.h` eventually includes `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h` to get the actual `#define __NR_write 1` macros, and so on.  There are standard rules for mapping arguments in order to registers.  ([Given in the ABI doc, IIRC](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)).

Comment: Ahh, you're right! I initially thought that I had to place the system call number in the `%rdi` register. Then I noticed that the return value was meant to be placed in `%rax`, and once I did that, along with placing the message in `%rsi` and the string length in `%rdx`, the output returned and all was right with the world. Thank you so much. I'd throw you an upvote, but it seems I don't have the reputation for it. Oh, and I understand and accept that using `libc` isn't the devil thanks to your explanation, but this was an exercise in understanding how these things work in assembly

Comment: @Azhraam: ya, I figured it was just a test-your-knowledge exercise.  IIRC, I grokked system calls separately from asm when I learned how things work under the hood.  C is a great language for messing around with system calls.  For making sure my asm does what I thought it did, I usually call it from C or just look at values in a debugger instead of actually printing anything.  `strace` is also a great tool for saving on log-printing while experimenting with system calls.  :P  `strace -o /dev/pts/XX` works well, where the pty is the `tty` from an xterm, to avoid mixing strace with normal output